# APIC 2018.210 OVA: URL format error when associating Analytics with Gateway

Tags: installation, virtual-machine, apiconnect

I am in the process of configuring the local Cloud. I have successfully registered: DataPower Gateway, Analytics and Portal services.

When I tried to associate the Analytics and Gateway services, I got this error message:

```
Associate Analytics has not been created!
Error validating the request body against definition
 '#/components/schemas/GatewayService' analytics_service_url Does not match format 'uri' 
(context: (root).analytics_service_url, line: 1, col: 26)
400
```

I don't find this message to be at all helpful. The Gateway urls all use ip addresses; Analytics is hostname.domain.name (FQDN) and it is the endpoint defined for analytics-client. The yaml file defines 'analytics-ingestion' as  different-hostname.domain.name.

I'd be really grateful for any guidance.

Regards, John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by really poor basic GUI design.

On the Associate Analytics Service page, there is only one row (Analytics Service | Availabilty Zone). On the far left is an extremely faint circular checkbox. I hadn't spotted it so it was not selected. It works when the checkbox selected.

The **Associate** button should be disabled when the checkbox isn't selected. That's the poor design. It would also help if the checkbox were to be easier to spot.

John